# A question about the proof of Hilbert's Basis Theorem

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, noetherian

I have a question regarding the [proof of Hilbert's Basis Theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_Basis_Theorem).

Say $I=(f_1,f_2,f_3,\dots)$ is an ideal in $A[x]$, where A is a Noetherian ring. Say we take the leading coefficients $a_i$ of all the polynomials generating $I$. Then the ideal $J$ generated by those coefficients will be finitely generated. We assume $J=(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_m)$. The proof says that $I=(f_1,f_2,\dots,f_m)$, where $f_i$ is the polynomial with leading coefficient $a_i$ for $i\in\{1,2,3,\dots,m\}$. How Hilbert goes about this (by successively selecting the polynomial of minimal degree) is well known, and can be seen in the link given.

My question is this:

Why does $f_i$ have to be the polynomial of minimal degree in $I$ for some $i\in\{1,2,3,\dots,m\}$? In fact, why do all $f_i$ have to be the minimal polynomials in the set $I\setminus (f_1,f_2,\dots,f_{i-1})$? I see no correlation between generating the ideal of leading coefficients and being the polynomial of lowest degree in $I$.

Comment: hint out of my head, **irreducibility** a necessary property for algebraic bases

Comment: @NikosM.- Why would that be? Why can't I have an ideal of the form $((x+1)(x+2))$?

Comment: @user26857- I'll try to explain my doubt: the ideal of the leading coefficients of the polynomials generating $I$ is $(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_m)$. All these are leading coefficients of some polynomials amongst the generators of $I$. Let those polynomials be $(f_1,f_2,\dots,f_m)$. So far so good. Now what do we do? We take $I$, and select the polynomial of lowest degree in $I$, hence getting $I\setminus (g)$, where $g$ is the polynomial of lowest degree. My question is, WHY does $g$ have to be $f_1$??

Comment: i am **not** sure but i think is related to the method of proof that uses existence of minimal elements, thus makes possible the existence of basis, one can have another base

Comment: @user26857- I feel the polynomials $f_1,f_2,\dots,f_m$ and the polynomials of lowest degrees in $I\setminus (g_1,g_2,\dots,g_n)$ should have nothing in common. They are completely different sets of polynomials. But the proof says $(g_1,_2,\dots,g_n)=(f_1,f_2,\dots,f_n)$ for each $n\leq m$. In short, my question is why do the polynomials, whose leading coefficients generate $J$, have to be the minimal polynomials in $I$ at various stages?

Comment: You choose the $f_i$ to be of minimal degree, they are not some polynomials amongst the generators. Then you want to show, that the collection $f_1, ... f_m$ already generates $I$. For that, note that we chose $f_{m+1}$ to be of minimal degree in $I\setminus (f_1, ..., f_m)$. Constructing $g$ gives you a polynomial of smaller degree in that set and thus a contradiction.

Comment: @freebird: You start by choosing a polynomial of minimal degree in $I$ and continue choosing polynomials of minimal degree in the ideal minus the ideal generated by the elements you already chose. You continue, until you generate $I$ with your elements (a priori, you could end up choosing all the elements of $I$ as generators of it, we don't care).$

Comment: @karl_christ- Is it possible that the set of minimal polynomials that we successively choose from $I$ deos not contain $\{f_1,f_2,\dots,f_m\}$? I see no reason why they should be!

Comment: Ok, I'm referring to your link and there $\{f_1, f_2, ...\}$ is the set of minimal polynomials, we successively choose and so it certainly contains the subset of its first $m$ elements.

Comment: @karl_christ- Sorry for the seemingly insanely stupid questions. I was looking at the proof all wrong, confusing notation. Thanks for your patient help mate.

Comment: no problem, glad I could help.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem was, but consider the case $A=\Bbb{Z}$ and $I$ the ideal of polynomials with only even coefficients. Thus $J=2\Bbb{Z}$. If you don't include the lowest degree polynomial with an even leading term, i.e. the constant $2$, you won't generate all of $I$. For example $2x$ won't work as a generator.